# Just a Question in Orientable Manifols

Tags: differential-geometry

Definition. Let $[M]$ be an orientation of the $n$ -dimensional manifold $M$, with
$orientation - preserving$ cover  {$(U_α, φ_a)$} and let $ω ∈ Ω^n_c (M)$. Define the integral of $τ$ by:

$\int_{[M]} τ = \sum_α \int_{U_α} ρ_α τ$

well this definition tells us the preserving the orientation via a part ion of unity but my question is Where the orientation involved in equality:

$\int_{[M]} τ = \sum_α \int_{U_α} ρ_α τ $

We also know that $ \sum_α \int_{R^n} (φ^{-1}_α)^*ρ_α τ $  but i can understand where the orientation involved in the integral? Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orientation of $(U,\phi)$ has an impact on the integral of the pull-back form. If $\phi$ preserves orientation, and $\omega$ is some top-form,

$$\int_{\phi(U)}\omega = \int_{U} \phi^{*}\omega$$

Where $\phi^* \omega$ is the pull-back of the form to $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. However, if $\phi$ reverses orientation

$$\int_{\phi(U)}\omega = -\int_{U} \phi^{*}\omega$$

What happens if you have a system of charts that doesn't maintain the same orientation? You'll end up integrating the negative of the form half the time, and the form itself the other half. This is clearly not going to give you a reasonable notion of an integral.

Comment: So $\int_{[M]} τ = \sum_α \int_{U_α} ρ_α τ $ = $ \sum_α \int_{R^n} (φ^{-1}_α)^*ρ_α τ $  the orientation is in $(φ^{-1}_α)^*$, i.e, in the pullback

Comment: That's correct.